# Drop down list dependent from another drop down tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I have one list with car brands in it and a second list with model names from these brands. I want to have two dropdown lists. First you select the brand and in the second dropdown you can select the model. But just models from the selected brand. I got the following code.

```
import tkinter as tk

brands = ["Bugatti","VW","Opel","Porsche"]
models = [["Veyron","Chiron"],
          ["Golf","Passat","Polo","Caddy"],
          ["Insignia","Corsa","Astra"],
          ["Taycan","Cayenne","911"]] 

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width= 500, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

tkvar = tk.StringVar(root)
tkvar.set('Choose')

popupMenu1 = OptionMenu(canvas, tkvar, *brands)
popupMenu1.pack()

def change_dropdown(*args):

    print("Chosen brand " + tkvar.get())

    for i in range(len(brands)):
        if tkvar.get() == brands[i]:
            print(models[i])

tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown)
root.mainloop()
```

How do i now create a second dropdown with the information from the list models. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Combobox to make dependent dropdown list

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
root = tkinter.Tk()
''' 
widgets are added here 
'''
brands = ["Bugatti","VW","Opel","Porsche"]

models = [["Veyron","Chiron"],
          ["Golf","Passat","Polo","Caddy"],
          ["Insignia","Corsa","Astra"],
          ["Taycan","Cayenne","911"]]

car_brand = ttk.Combobox(root, width=37, value=(brands))
car_brand.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky='w')

def callback(eventObject):
    abc = eventObject.widget.get()
    car = car_brand.get()
    index=brands.index(car)
    car_model.config(values=models[index])

car_model = ttk.Combobox(root, width=37)
car_model.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky='w')
car_model.bind('<Button-1>', callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How do i get this to work? Imported ttk and put it into the loop. I get two dropdown menus but if i want to selct the model i always get a "Exception in Tkinter callback"

Comment: @Kuempsmichi first you have to select car brand then when we click on model dropdown it fetch the value of brand and populate the dropdown of model of selected brand.

Comment: I know how it should work but as i said if i use your code it doesnt work. How do  i need to modify your code. Could you send me the entire code if its working for you?

Comment: @Kuempsmichi use this code. Its working properly on my system.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

brands = ["Bugatti","VW","Opel","Porsche"]
models = [["Veyron","Chiron"],
          ["Golf","Passat","Polo","Caddy"],
          ["Insignia","Corsa","Astra"],
          ["Taycan","Cayenne","911"]]

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width= 500, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

tkvar = tk.StringVar(root)
tkvar.set('Choose')

tkvar2 = tk.StringVar(root)
tkvar2.set('Model')

popupMenu1 = tk.OptionMenu(canvas, tkvar, *brands)
popupMenu1.pack()


popupMenu2 = tk.OptionMenu(canvas, tkvar2, [])
popupMenu2.pack()

def change_dropdown(*args):

    print("Chosen brand " + tkvar.get())
    for i in range(len(brands)):
        if tkvar.get() == brands[i]:
            popupMenu2["menu"].delete(0, "end")
            for item in models[i]:
                   popupMenu2['menu'].add_command(label=item, command=tk._setit(tkvar2, item))


tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I also tried that one but the Problem is, if i change the brand again it creates a third dropdown and so on. Is there a way that the dropdown gets overwritten and not a new one created?