# How can you make 3 (or 4) nested binded comboxes uting Tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to make a GUI that has binding dropdowns that rely off the previous dropdown. The format that I am trying to achieve is as follows:

1. Select a {level 1}
2. Select a {level 2} - bound to level 1
3. Select a {level 3} - bound to level 2
4. Select an {level 4} - bound to level 3

The code that I have been working on is seen below. This was derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066179/drop-down-list-dependent-from-another-drop-down-tkinter):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
root = tkinter.Tk()
''' 
widgets are added here 
'''
brands = ["Bugatti","BMW"]

models = [["Veyron","Golf"],
          ["330M"]]

Zip = [[["TEST1"],["TEST2"]],[["TEST3"]]]

car_brand = ttk.Combobox(root, width=37, value=(brands))
car_brand.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky='w')

def callback(eventObject):
    abc = eventObject.widget.get()
    car = car_brand.get()
    index=brands.index(car)
    car_model.config(values=models[index])

car_model = ttk.Combobox(root, width=37)
car_model.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky='w')
car_model.bind('<Button-1>', callback)

def callback2(eventObject):
    abc = eventObject.widget.get()
    y = car_model.get()
    index=models.index(y)
    xx.config(values=Zip[index])

xx = ttk.Combobox(root, width=37)
xx.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky='w')
xx.bind('<Button-1>', callback2)

root.mainloop()
```

I am probably really close, but I need some help getting it to work.

**Update:**
Thank you @JacksonPro for your answer. I needed to adjust it a little bit to allow for grid placements. See below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



cars = {"Bugatti":["Veyron","Golf"] ,"BMW":["330M"]}

_zip = [[["TEST1"],["TEST11"]],[["TEST2"],["Hello"],["World"]],["TEST3"]]

lst = [x for y in list(cars.values()) for x in y]


def change_dropdown(*args):

    print("Chosen brand " + tkvar.get())

    if args[0] == 'PY_VAR0':
        for x, y in cars.items():
            if tkvar.get() == x:
                tkvar2.set(y[0])
                popupMenu2.configure(values=y)
        
    if args[0] == 'PY_VAR1':
        for x, y in zip(lst, _zip):
            if tkvar2.get() == x:            
                tkvar3.set(y[0])
                popupMenu3.configure(values=y)
        
    return
    
root = tk.Tk()
# canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width= 500, bg="white")
root.geometry('500x100')
font = ("Courier", 16, "bold")
# canvas.pack()

tkvar = tk.StringVar(root)
tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown)

tkvar2 = tk.StringVar(root)
tkvar2.trace('w', change_dropdown)

tkvar3 = tk.StringVar(root)

labelTop = tk.Label(root, text = "Select a State")
labelTop.grid(column=0, row=0)
popupMenu1 = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=tkvar, values=list(cars.keys()))
popupMenu1.grid(row=0, column=1)
# popupMenu1.pack()

popupMenu2 = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=tkvar2, values=[])
popupMenu2.grid(row=1, column=1)
# popupMenu2.pack()

popupMenu3 = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=tkvar3, values=[])
popupMenu3.grid(row=2, column=1)
# popupMenu3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: There is no linkage between `state` and `CBSA`, and between `CBSA` and `Zip`. So how can `CBSA` depend on `state`, and `Zip` depend on `CBSA`?

Comment: Updated question based off a closer working model that more aligns with my overall design. Need to see "Zip" entries fill into the third dropdown based off the 2nd dropdown's selection. This is where I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which you can improve further by add zip code too.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

cars = {"Bugatti":["Veyron","Golf"] ,"BMW":["330M"]}
    

def change_dropdown(*args):

    print("Chosen brand " + tkvar.get())

    for x, y in cars.items():
        if tkvar.get() == x:
            tkvar2.set(y[0])
            popupMenu2.configure(values=y)
        
     
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width= 500, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

tkvar = tk.StringVar(root)

tkvar2 = tk.StringVar(root)

tkvar3 = tk.StringVar(root)

popupMenu1 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, textvariable=tkvar, values=list(cars.keys()))
popupMenu1.pack()
popupMenu1.bind('<<comboboxselected>>', change_dropdown)

popupMenu2 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, textvariable=tkvar2, values=[])
popupMenu2.pack()
popupMenu1.bind('<<comboboxselected>>', change_dropdown)

popupMenu3 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, textvariable=tkvar3, values=[])
popupMenu3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Update:**

here is the fully functioning code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

cars = {"Bugatti":["Veyron","Golf"] ,"BMW":["330M"]}

_zip = [["TEST1"],["TEST2"],["TEST3"]]

lst = [x for y in list(cars.values()) for x in y]


def change_dropdown(*args):

    print("Chosen brand " + tkvar.get())

    if args[0] == 'PY_VAR0':
        for x, y in cars.items():
            if tkvar.get() == x:
                tkvar2.set(y[0])
                popupMenu2.configure(values=y)
        
    if args[0] == 'PY_VAR1':
        for x, y in zip(lst, _zip):
            if tkvar2.get() == x:            
                tkvar3.set(y[0])
                popupMenu3.configure(values=y)
        
    return
    
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width= 500, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

tkvar = tk.StringVar(root)
tkvar.trace('w', change_dropdown)

tkvar2 = tk.StringVar(root)
tkvar2.trace('w', change_dropdown)

tkvar3 = tk.StringVar(root)

popupMenu1 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, textvariable=tkvar, values=list(cars.keys()))
popupMenu1.pack()

popupMenu2 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, textvariable=tkvar2, values=[])
popupMenu2.pack()

popupMenu3 = ttk.Combobox(canvas, textvariable=tkvar3, values=[])
popupMenu3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @JacksonPro! This was very helpful. I had to make some slight alterations to have multiple options for the 3rd dropdown options; such as: _zip = [[["TEST1"],["TEST11"]],[["TEST2"],["Hello"],["World"]],["TEST3"]]. But this helps get me to the general structure that I am looking for.

Comment: I made some further changes; see update section in the original post. I needed to account for grid placement, which I did by adjusting your answer.

Comment: @AndrewHicks you need to give row and column weight of 1: `tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, (0,1,2), weight=1)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, (0,1,2), weight=1)`

Comment: So this helps space them out and resizes them based off the size of the window? That's pretty neat! Thanks!

Comment: So when I run this twice, on the second run the 2nd and 3rd dropdowns are blank. The only work around I have found is to reset the kernel (using Jupyter Notebooks). Any idea as to why that is?

Comment: @AndrewHicks It works fine for me. I am not using jupyter notebook so, I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Oh...just converted my .ipynb file to a .py file and it works.

Comment: I made a follow-up question. Any insight you have would be greatly appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387049/need-help-adjusting-a-multi-bound-tkinter-combobox-python-script-to-a-nested-dic