# Dropdown files list dependent from another dropdown folder list

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system, dropdown, openfiledialog

I need help on how to do dependent dropdown files list from another dropdown folder list.
In one folder, I have 5 List of folder, then for each folder, I have 5 list of files. In my code, I already make 2 dropdown function which is 1st dropdown : list out all the folder . 2nd dropdown : I want make a dependent list in 2nd dropdown which is depend on the folder that I have select in 1st dropdown. is that possible?

For example:

Directory : 'C:\Users\TestFile'

folder List :
-folder1
-folder2
-folder3
-folder4
-folder5

file list in each folder:
folder1 : apple1,apple2,apple3,.....
folder2 : orange1,orange2,orange3,.....
folder3 : grape1,grape2,grape3,.....
folder4 : lych1,lych2,lych3,.....
folder5 : strwberry1,strwberry2,strwberry3,.....

So if i select folder1 in my first dropdown, I want all files (apple1,apple2,apple3,..... )that in folder1 listed out in 2nd dropdown.

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser
from webbrowser import open as openlink
import urllib

def open(file_menu):
    filename = file_menu.get()

    open_in_browser_link = f"file://{os.path.join(folder, filename)}"
    print(open_in_browser_link)

    webbrowser.open(open_in_browser_link)



def clear_data():
#    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    return None



folder = os.path.realpath(r'C:\Users\TestFile')
filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder)]

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry('1200x800')
master.title('THB')

# Frame for TreeView
frame0 = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="Chapter",background="light grey")
frame0.place(height=500, width=1200, rely=0.0, relx=0.0)

optmenu = ttk.Combobox(frame0, values=filelist, state='readonly')
optmenu.pack()
optmenu.set("Chapter")

optmenu1 = ttk.Combobox(frame0, values=????, state='readonly')
optmenu1.pack()
optmenu1.set("SubChapter")

button_select = tk.Button(frame0, text="Show Data",
                          width=15,
                          height=2,
                          compound=tk.CENTER,
                          command=partial(open, optmenu1))

button_select.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
button_select.pack(side=tk.TOP)


master.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with just the code needed to illustrate the problem — and get rid of all those imports not being used.

Comment: I made something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65338040/12198502) which you can refer to. But do note that it isn't the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic algorithm behind the code want can be split as follows:

- bind each option select signal of the first combobox to a function,
- that scans a directory and sets the available files to the second combobox.

Now, the important part for this operation is:

```py
optmenu.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", onSelect)

...
...

def onSelect(event):
    folder_name = filelist[event.widget.current()]
    folder_path = os.path.join(folder, folder_name)

    print(f"folder selected:{folder_name}, folder_path:{folder_path}, index:{event.widget.current()}")

    global sub_files
    sub_files = []
    for f_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        sub_files.append(f_name)
    print(sub_files)

    optmenu1['values'] = sub_files  # set sub directories to combobox
```

The complete code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
# import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser
from webbrowser import open as openlink
import urllib


def open(file_menu):
    filename = file_menu.get()

    open_in_browser_link = f"file://{os.path.join(folder, filename)}"
    print(open_in_browser_link)

    webbrowser.open(open_in_browser_link)


def clear_data():
    #    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    return None


def onSelect(event):
    folder_name = filelist[event.widget.current()]
    folder_path = os.path.join(folder, folder_name)

    print(f"folder selected:{folder_name}, folder_path:{folder_path}, index:{event.widget.current()}")

    global sub_files
    sub_files = []
    for f_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        sub_files.append(f_name)
    print(sub_files)

    optmenu1['values'] = sub_files  # set sub directories to combobox


folder = os.path.realpath(r'C:\Users\TestFile')
sub_files = []
# folder = os.path.realpath(r'./testing')
filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder)]

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry('1200x800')
master.title('THB')

# Frame for TreeView
frame0 = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="Chapter", background="light grey")
frame0.place(height=500, width=1200, rely=0.0, relx=0.0)

optmenu = ttk.Combobox(frame0, values=filelist, state='readonly')
optmenu.pack()
optmenu.set("Chapter")
optmenu.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", onSelect)

optmenu1 = ttk.Combobox(frame0, values=[], state='readonly')
optmenu1.pack()
optmenu1.set("SubChapter")

button_select = tk.Button(frame0, text="Show Data",
                          width=15,
                          height=2,
                          compound=tk.CENTER,
                          command=partial(open, optmenu1))

button_select.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
button_select.pack(side=tk.TOP)

master.mainloop()
```

Now, this code, opens the `C:\Users\TestFile` folder, and scans each direcotry and sets to first combobox (`optmenu`).

Then, when you select any one option in `optmenu`, it calls the `onSelect()` function. This `onSelect` function, read all files available inside the folder selected in `optmenu`, and shows the available files in `optmenu1`.